# Probability of flipping a Hershey's Kiss and it landing on its base

Tags: probability, solid-geometry

I, like many other AP Statistics students, just spent an entire class flipping Hershey's Kisses and trying to determine the empirical probability of landing it on its base. This led me to wonder if there was a way to actually calculate the probability. To simplify, I decided that instead I would flip a right circular cone with $d = h,$ ignoring the wrapper and any imperfections in the shape. My first idea was to simply use surface area, getting $$\dfrac{\pi r^2}{\pi r(r + \sqrt{r^2 + h^2})} = \dfrac{r}{r + \sqrt{r^2 + (2r)^2}} = \dfrac{1}{1 + \sqrt{5}} \approx \boxed{0.309}$$

Obviously, there are some flaws with this approximation. Is there a better way to solve this? I have a sneaking suspicion that moment of inertia comes into play. If this is the case, should I post this in a different forum? Note that the experimental probability is 0.35.

Comment: I imagine this entirely depends on the flipping distribution. How are you flipping the cones?

Comment: One way to model this might be to imagine holding the cone in a random orientation, then dropping it onto a flat surface (without rotation) so that the key factor would be the position of the centre of mass. This of course neglects a lot of factors but might give you a good first approximation (NB it's worth considering the simpler case of a coin to see why surface area might not be the best approach; as soon as you allow the coin to have any thickness it breaks down)

Comment: (I'm suggesting, by the way, that for a realistic flip, aerodynamics aren't going to play a part. If you dropped them out of a plane you may need a different model - and to factor in structural integrity)

Comment: For people outside the US : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hershey%27s_Kisses

Comment: Brevan, similar to how one would flip a coin. Why would it make a difference?

Comment: @JeanMarie they are much less conical than I was expecting. It seems the centre of mass would be much lower than for a cone.

Comment: @trying How long was this class? I could imagine there being some deformation after, say, the first million flips ;-)

Comment: @trying and by flipping a coin properly you can guarantee the same outcome every time. It's true that small pertubations get magnified, but if you eg always start with the cone on its base and flip it once, then I'd guess it will land back on its base significantly often. The precise definition of "flipping" you use determines a distribution for how it will land. The same is true of coin flips. You obviously want something to be uniformly random, but what? Compare, for example, to the Bertrand Paradox.

Answer (score 2):

Modelling the Hershey's Kiss as a cone with uniform density, base radius $r$ and height $h$, we find its centre of mass $G$ is at a point $\frac{h}{4}$ above the centre of the base. A cross-section through the apex and the centre of the base is shown below:

[image]

If we assume the cone's orientation when it lands is random, the probability it lands on its base is the angle $\angle AGB$ divided by $2\pi$, ie
$$p=\frac{1}{\pi} \tan^{-1}\frac{4r}{h}$$

In the case $h=2r$, this works out to be $p=0.3524$ (which is ridiculously close to the numerical value found!).

---

I would suggest the key assumption here is about how the cone lands. It is, of course, spinning, and will have angular momentum; so the orientation at the moment it lands alone isn't enough to work out if it will fall onto the base. You can imagine cases where its momentum causes it to topple and land on the curved surface. However, this happens in the other direction too so, although things won't cancel out exactly, the error will be mitigated.